# Play 2.0 + Bootstrap3: Showing active navigation item

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am using the following syntax in the Playframework 2.0 to figure out the given Bootstrap nav li should be active or not, but it doesn't work! Any idea what I missed here?

The following is snippet from my playframework template where I am trying to make Home li as active if the current request path is same as routes index/home

```
@* Home page is active. *@
<li class=@{"active".when("@request.path" == "@routes.Application.index()")}>
  <a href="@routes.Application.index()">Home</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm don't know play, but using their template engine in my projects.

How about this way:

```
@* Home page is active. *@
<li class=@{if (request.path == routes.Application.index().toString()) "active" else ""}>
  <a href="@routes.Application.index()">Home</a>
</li>
```

Comment: @Alexlv - it doesn't work because routes.Application.index() returns reference of class named `Call` which returns false when compared with `String` output from `request.path`. Thank you.

Comment: @Hemant I think my solution would also worked if you call toString on `index()`, but i'm not sure.

Comment: @Alexlv - Yes it works after toString() or url is called on output of index(). I learned this from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<li class="@("active".when(request.path == controllers.routes.Application.index().toString()))">
  <a href="@routes.Application.index()">Home</a>
</li>
```

Comment: your solution worked! It was invocation of `toString()` on `routes.Application.index()` which made the difference. Later I debugged and found it was because routes.Application.index() returns reference to class named `Call` which have property named `url` Also, instead of `routes.Application.index().toString()` we can also use `routes.Application.index().url`. Thank you buddy!